# What are the purposes of these three connection options for printing the label in ZPL?

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, network-programming, zebra-printers

I have these three radio button inside the group box named Printer Connection in the windows form:

a. Network
b. Serial
   - dropdownlist
c. Web service

User has to choose one of the option from above before printing any labels or clicking the button Print Label. If someone would explain about the purpose of web service and the scenario how it can be utilize to connect to the printer and printing label. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand what app you are using but I have to imagine you are using something based off of the Java SDK by Zebra. In this SDK there is a Web Services SDK. It comes with a .war file that gets added to a Tomcat server. Printers have a set of settings which when configured will have the pritners establish a connection to the server with the .war file installed. Once the printer has connected you can use the Java SDK functions to communicated with the printer from that server.

This explanation is probably over simplified, but if you look through the help documentation on the SDK you will probably get a better explanation.

Comment: Thank you banno. I am using windows application. I want to know in the windows application why they have three options to connect to print the label in Zebra. In network option, we select the client name and IP address and will be connected to the printer. In case of Serial, we do have port to select from in the win form. And I am expecting that how web service is connected? and why three options are provided if all of their function is to connect to the printer and print label? Thank you!

Comment: web services takes the printer serial number, but the printer has to connect in.